# Php xml encoding issue

Tags: php, xml, parsing, encoding

Hi guys after 5 hours of research and trying everything I'm so desperate so I write here.
I have an XML file coming from a third party. When I try to parse it with `SimpleXMLElement` it simply says that the string is not in valid XML format and I also found out that this happens due to ANSI encoding the XML file is having. I tried converting the file to UTF-8 -> it gets read by the parser but all my Cyrillic symbols are lost, replaced by meaningless chars.
Then in notepad++ I copied the content created a file with utf8 encoding and pasted the content -> it was just fine and got read by the parser. I tried to do it with code but no result -> I get contents of the file, create a file with first bytes, the bytes of UTF-8 file, output the content and when I open it -> meaningless chars instead of Cyrillic. Help me please I really need to convert this file to UTF-8 valid for the XML parser or could you please tell me another way to parse the file from XML to array.

Comment: You should think of SO sooner ;) What happens if you open the xml file in a browser, do you get a parse error then?

Comment: Do you know what encoding the original file is in? iso8859-5?

Comment: It's not opening in chrome nor IE9. Notepad says that the encoding is ANSI, I dont know...

Comment: Cannot be ANSI, ANSI does not have any support for Cyrillic characters. Can you upload the original file somewhere, so we might have a look?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php
and
http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: I forgot to mension that After UTF-8 encode and then decode the data is lost... for good resulting in ????????? I tried iconv -> can you be more specific about it, maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: when outputting the working file, try using utf8_decode() on the strings that need to be outputted correctly. just try it, I don't think you did. let me know how it works out. also, give iconv a shot, try iconv('UTF-8','CP-1251',$string); or try ISO-8859-5 instead of CP-1251

Comment: Yes i did try it and told you that it decodes into ?????...
`Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-8' to `CP-1251' is not allowed`. I guess the xml file is broken...

Comment: try different charsets, maybe it's KOI8 or something. I think utf8_decode would be a more simple path

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out what encoding the original XML file is in, then you can use [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert it to UTF8.

Comment: If browsers refuse to open it... I guess you can use Word to open the file and tell you the encoding: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-HA010121249.aspx#BM2